# Increment +1 cells with True value

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to take a set of names with check boxes next to them and make a system so that you can check some of the names (mark them as "True") and click a button. It would then increment +1 the value next to the names of the people marked true.

Here is a link to a sample sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gf-BrXXR0cAYCn7bMkvvK65R290NXbP9D6aA68c06C8/edit?usp=sharing

If column A, row 2 (Tim's row) is marked true, I want to increment the value in column C, row 2 by one, so Tim would have a running total of tardies next to his name.

I hope this is do-able. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Now I know what you're trying to get)
In order to increment a value via the press of a button, as far as I know you have to use scripts (`Tools -> Script Editor`). Here's something I threw together:

```
// editCell takes the cell to edit and it's new value
function editCell(cellName, value) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cellName).setValue(value);
}

// getCell takes the cell's value and returns it
function getCell(cellName) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cellName).getValue();
}

// plusOne adds one to the field supplied. It's linked to the button in the sheet
function plusOne() {
  editCell("C2",getCell("C2")+1);
}
```

In order to make it work, you may need to change the targeted Cell (currently `C2`). You'll also need to create a drawing (`Insert -> Drawing`) which will act as the button you'll be able to press. Once inserted, click on the three dots on it and click on `Link Script`. Type in `plusOne`. When executing it the first time, it'll ask you to authenticate the use of scripts.
That should do the trick. I hope you have some understanding of Java Script though (to modify the code to your needs optimally).

---

### Edit - Expandable version

So, to make every number behind a ticked field increase by one, you can use this version of the code:

```
// Adds one to every field within "AddArea" that has a tick in front of it. It's linked to the button in the sheet.
function plusOne() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = ss.getRange("AddArea");
  var values = range.getValues();
  var newValues = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < range.getNumRows(); ++i) {
    var row = values[i];

    if(row[0]) {
      newValues.push([true, row[1]+1]);
    }
    else {
      newValues.push([false, row[1]]);
    }
  }
  range.setValues(newValues);
}
```

You need to define a custom named area, named "AddArea" (`Data -> Labeled Areas` [or similar]), link the script to a button and allow the script to be run. This was hard but very fun to figure out.

[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mr48zdd90lj8LifiGK_kdzE_dy3J3oPntsu5PLZVreM/edit?usp=sharing) for reference (updated)

Comment: I think I gave a poor example. I would like to be able to check multiple people's boxes at once, then run the script to apply +1 to the numbers of those people with their boxes checked. So, the script needs to:   1. Check column A for all "true" statements, then increment column C for all rows that were "true" in column A. So if I mark Jim, Angie and John tardy, one button push will raise their count by 1 each.

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved with just, for example for C2:

```
=A2+C2
```

but you would need to turn on iterative calculation (File > Spreadsheet settings... > Calculation [Max. `1` is adequate]) and I would not really recommend that over a trigger with Google Apps Script.